# Removing repeated values from array with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

These are the full instructions for what I am trying to accomplish :

You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

This is the solution I have:

```
function destroyer(arr) {     
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.slice(0,1);
  return arr.filter(function(elements) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```

Keep in mind that there could be any number of arguments (not just 2 or 3).
The solution I have isn't working. What is wrong with my current solution and how can I fix it with an explanation?

Comment: can you give sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin not a job interview. Just online training for self-interest.

Comment: @gurvinder372 ([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) <- that  is a sample input, which should return [1,1]
This could be any set of numbers, with any amount of arguments though..

Comment: @victoria i think you need to pass the arguments also in an array. then you can take each element in argument array and remove from your original array

Comment: @AnoopLL with 'var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)' aren't I already turning it into an array? and with the filter method am i not filtering out any of the elements that do not meet the indexOf condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost working. 
The problems:

- `args.slice(0,1);` does not modify the array (anyway this method just returns an array with the first element). Use `args.shift()` instead to remove the first element
- `function(elements)` should be `function(element)` in the filter callback.

A working solution:

```
function destroyer(arr) {     
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.shift();
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 5, 5], 1, 5)); // prints [2, 3]
```

Check the working [demo](http://jsbin.com/baceqijaro/1/edit?js,console).